# MapKit repsondsToSelector for setUserTrackingMode in IOS 4.3.3

Tags: ios, dictionary, ios4, ios5

I have the following code

```
BOOL ios5 = [mapview respondsToSelector:@selector(setUserTrackingMode:animated:)];
if(ios5)
{
    if(compass && tracking)
        [mapview setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:YES];
    else if (tracking)
        [mapview setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
    else
        [mapview setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeNone animated:YES];
}
else
{
    // Do it the version 4.0 way
}
```

It works as expected depending on whether I have the compass or tracking flags on and tracks the user location in iOS 5.

However, it also works in version 4.3.3 which is the other device I'm testing on. It seems to respond to the selector and actually behaves as it does in iOS 5.

Is this because the functionality was in iOS 4 but not made public and I run the risk of the app being rejected for that reason?

Can anyone shed some light on this?
thanks
Donie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're doing the right thing by checking the functionality first before using it. It doesn't matter what version you're running on, that API is **already** documented. By doing it this way you are providing backwards compatibility to your 4.3 users.

Comment: But I thought the functionality would only be available to iOS 5+ users? API document says it was introduced in version 5.

Comment: You are using an API that is documented AND you are doing the `respondsToSelector:` check to protect your users who do not have IOS 5.0. You are being a good citizen here and I don't believe it will be your responsibility if that `respondsToSelector` does work on a version lower than 5.0. I will find it unreasonable if Apple says otherwise because they never advised in any of their docs to check for device version, but they do tell us that we should check for functionality instead.